# I can't connect using ssh key pairs, debug shows it searches for a -cert file

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I'm working on a Windows 10 machine. I want to use the ssh command to connect to the server.

I have generated a pair of ssh keys using OpenSsh and sent the public key to the server.
I have a config file with the server settings and where the private key is.

My private key is in file C:/Users/MyUser/.ssh/ssh_key_CLM.
I have to mention that I can connect using MobaXTerm to the respective server, using the respective ssh key pair.

The ssh command in PowerShell does not connect. If a do `ssh servername -vvv`, I get:

```
ssh : OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
At line:1 char:1
+ ssh servername -vvv
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (OpenSSH_for_Win... LibreSSL 3.0.2:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\MyUser/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\MyUser/.ssh/config line 16: Applying options for servername 
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xxx.xxx.xx.xx is address
debug1: Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe"  -vvv -W "[%h]:%p" 
xx-ssh-public
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe"  -vvv -W "[xxx.xxx.xx.xx]:2212" 
xx-ssh-public
debug3: spawning "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe"  -vvv -W "[xxx.xxx.xx.xx]:2212" xx-ssh-public
debug3: w32_getpeername ERROR: not sock :2
# debug1: identity file C:/Users/MyUser/.ssh/ssh_key_CLM type 3
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/MyUser/.ssh/ssh_key_CLM-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/MyUser/.ssh/ssh_key_CLM-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:/Users/MyUser/.ssh/ssh_key_CLM-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\MyUser/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\MyUser/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for xxx-ssh-public
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xxx.xxx.xx.xxx is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to xxx-ssh-public [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10013, io:00000188968EF9A0
debug1: connect to address xxx.xxx.xx.xxx port 22: Permission denied
ssh: connect to host xx-ssh-public port 22: Permission denied
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

**Question**

What does type *3 mean* (in the above output) and why does it look afterwards for C:/Users/MyUser/.ssh/ssh_key_CLM-cert file?
How do I connect to the server?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a communication problem.
If you have a firewall, disable it temporarily and see if it works.